# Outputting VBA results to text file in Outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to make the below output into a text file on my desktop. I am very new (as in today) and I found the below script online, I have gotten my head around what each but does however I am struggling to make it output as a text file. I am not sure where the commands should go (beginning middle or end?) to do this. I have found one command but I am  getting errors left right and centre. Please help.

```
Sub CountItemsInMBX()

Dim outapp As Outlook.Application
Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim olns As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olns = outapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")


Debug.Print GetSubFolderCount(olns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent)

End Sub

Function GetSubFolderCount(objParentFolder As MAPIFolder) As Long
Dim currentFolders As Folders
Dim fldCurrent As MAPIFolder


Set currentFolders = objParentFolder.Folders
If currentFolders.Count > 0 Then

Set fldCurrent = currentFolders.GetFirst
While Not fldCurrent Is Nothing
TempFolderCount = TempFolderCount + GetSubFolderCount(fldCurrent)
Set fldCurrent = currentFolders.GetNext
Wend
Debug.Print objParentFolder.Name & " - " & objParentFolder.Items.Count
GetSubFolderCount = TempFolderCount + objParentFolder.Items.Count
Else
Debug.Print objParentFolder.Name & " - " & objParentFolder.Items.Count
GetSubFolderCount = objParentFolder.Items.Count

End If

End Function
```

Comment: The code you posted simply lists the count of items in each folder.  And you really have not defined what output you want.  Please help us out.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, OP wants to print to a text file instead of the immediate window.

Comment: To write to a file what your Debug.Print produces, you can either use 'Open For Output... and Print' or File System Object  Text Stream...'. Not near my PC at the moment, but can give examples tomorrow. Lots of samples online if you Google: vba write to text file

Comment: Thanks Wayne if you can let me know what you think is best I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is your code, converted to call a function, passing it a string, that will write to a text file.  Change the file path & name to suit your needs.

Personally, I don't like the call method because it is a waste to check if the file exists, etc. for every call. However, since your code had two subroutines that need to write text, I was too lazy to embed the proper code in your code. You could either leave as is (if seldom used), or combine together if desired.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountItemsInMBX()
Dim outapp  As Outlook.Application
Dim olns    As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olns = outapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'Debug.Print GetSubFolderCount(olns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent)
    Write_To_MyLog GetSubFolderCount(olns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent)
End Sub

Function GetSubFolderCount(objParentFolder As MAPIFolder) As Long
Dim currentFolders  As Folders
Dim fldCurrent      As MAPIFolder
Dim TempFolderCount As Integer

    Set currentFolders = objParentFolder.Folders
    If currentFolders.Count > 0 Then

        Set fldCurrent = currentFolders.GetFirst
        While Not fldCurrent Is Nothing
            TempFolderCount = TempFolderCount + GetSubFolderCount(fldCurrent)
            Set fldCurrent = currentFolders.GetNext
        Wend
        'Debug.Print objParentFolder.Name & " - " & objParentFolder.Items.Count
        Write_To_MyLog objParentFolder.Name & " - " & objParentFolder.Items.Count
        GetSubFolderCount = TempFolderCount + objParentFolder.Items.Count
    Else
        'Debug.Print objParentFolder.Name & " - " & objParentFolder.Items.Count
        Write_To_MyLog objParentFolder.Name & " - " & objParentFolder.Items.Count
        GetSubFolderCount = objParentFolder.Items.Count

    End If

End Function

Public Function Write_To_MyLog(sText As String)
Dim oFSO        As FileSystemObject
Dim oFile       As File
Dim oStream     As TextStream

    On Error GoTo Error_trap

    Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject

    If Not oFSO.FileExists("C:\Temp\Outlook_Folders.txt") Then
        Set oStream = oFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\Outlook_Folders.txt")
        oStream.WriteLine " "
    Else
        Set oFile = oFSO.GetFile("C:\Temp\Outlook_Folders.txt")
        Set oStream = oFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForAppending, TristateMixed)
    End If

    oStream.WriteLine sText
    oStream.Close
    Set oStream = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing

Early_Exit:
    Exit Function

Error_trap:
Dim strError    As String

    strError = "In subroutine: Write_To_MyLog " & vbCrLf & _
                Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
                        "At Line: " & Erl
    Err.Source = "Module_Utilities: Write_To_MyLog  at Line: " & Erl
    MsgBox "Error: " & strError
    'Write_To_Log strError   ' This is a call to a function that saves the error info to a database table.
    Resume Early_Exit
    Resume Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thank Wayne! That was spot on!